# FactoryBot - Unilitialized constant - Ruby project (not rails!)

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I am trying to set up a test on a very basic ruby project(not rails) with the factorybot gem, but can't find a way to make it work. I followed the guide https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md
which is just installing the gem, run bundle install and add to my spec/spec_helper.rb this configuration:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    FactoryBot.find_definitions
  end
end
```

Then I created a factories/order_factories.rb file inside the spec folder like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :restaurant do
    id { 3 }
    cooking_time  { 15 }
    x { 0 }
    y { 0}
  end
    factory :customer do
    id { 1 }
    x { 1 }
    y { 1 }
  end
end
```

and require it from the spec file of the object I want to test. The file is order_spec.rb like this :

```
require_relative './factories/order_factories'

let(:restaurant) { create(:restaurant) }

  describe "Order", :order do
    it "should be initialized with a hash of properties" do
      properties = {  :customer => 1, :restaurant => 3 }
      order = Order.new(properties)
      expect(order).to be_a(Order)
    end
  end
```

I already tried tones of other file organisation with proper require, but keep on having the FactoryBot constant not initialized. I wonder if my Gemfile.lock is not the origin of the problem:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activesupport (6.1.3.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.8)
    diff-lcs (1.4.4)
    factory_bot (6.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    i18n (1.8.10)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    minitest (5.14.4)
    rspec (3.10.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.10.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.10.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-core (3.10.1)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.10.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.10.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-support (3.10.2)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-18

DEPENDENCIES
  factory_bot
  rspec (~> 3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.16
```

Is there something I am missing here?

my spec/spec_helper.rb file :

```
 require "factory_bot"
    
    
    RSpec.configure do |config|
    
      config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
    
      config.before(:suite) do
        FactoryBot.find_definitions
      end
    
    
      config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    
        expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
    
      end
    
      config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    
        mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
      end
    
      config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
    
    end
```

I edited my order_spec.rb like this :

```
require_relative "./spec_helper"
require "factory_bot"
require_relative './factories/order_factories'
```

but still not working..

Comment: Somehow you need to get access to the files in the library, did you add the require (`require "factory_bot"`)?

Comment: No, I didn't. Where should I require "factory_bot"? I tried to require it in my order_spec.rb but I got the same unitialized constant error

Comment: It might be in your `spec/spec_helper.rb` file just before any use of the FactoryBot module.

Comment: "I tried to require it in my order_spec.rb but I got the same unitialized constant error", yes, because the spec_helper runs before the order_spec.rb file, so the library isn't required yet.

Comment: I just tried, same error ;(

Comment: I edited the post with the spec_helper.rb file, do you see anything wrong? (Thanks @SebastianPalma !!)

Comment: You need to require the spec_helper file in your spec files, try adding `require "spec/spec_helper"` (don't know if that path is ok, if not update your answer with the resulting error).

Comment: ... requiring the spec_helper in your order_spec.rb file, I meant.

Comment: I edited the post, still not working. Would you be ok to move to chat?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Rails model with an attribute named `y`, and you have a factory that sets this attribute, it freaks out FactoryBot. It's not FactoryBot's fault, see error https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/1397

Solution is to set the `y` attribute via

```
add_attribute(:y) { 0 }
```